# Wait for auth request to complete before checking if user is logged in with route guards

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-router, angular-router-guards

EDITED BELOW

I don't want to make a call to determine if a user is authenticated every time the route changes, but I do want to check that if they refresh the page on an authenticated route, they can access it. I can't seem to make this work.

I have a service that simply checks the session with the api, like this:

```ts
    authenticate(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.http.post<boolean>(this._authUrl, {}, {})
    }
```

Endpoint literally returns a `true` or `false`. I run this on the `app.component` so it's the first thing that happens and it never needs to request that again.

```ts
   ngOnInit() {
        this.userService.authenticate().subscribe((response) => {
            this.userService.loggedIn = response;
        })

    }
```

I then have a route defined like this:

```ts
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
```

Then in my `authguard` service, I have this:

```ts
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any{
    return this.userService.loggedIn
    })
}
```

This works just fine if you land on `/` and navigate to `/dashboard`. But if you're logged in and refresh the page on `/dashboard`, the component never loads. It loads the navigation and whatnot, but doesn't load the dashboard component or template. `/authenticate` does run but seems the route guard already looks at `loggedIn` before the endpoint responds.

I tried putting the `loggedIn` variable into an observable using `of`, that didn't seem to make any difference, end result was the same.

Everything I've looked up seems to be for checking authentication via a URL and using observables that way, but I really don't want to have to make an http request when it already knows the user is authenticated from the first initial request.

***Edit:***
I think a better way to think about this is, I want the `/authenticate` response to be ready before loading *anything else*. With route guard, I'd have to lock the landing page behind being logged in, and I don't want to do that. But I also want the response of `/authenticate` to be accessible by the root `app.component` because thats where my navigation is as well as an indicator to the user that they're logged in.

So it seems to make sense to me that if I could tell angular to wait on `/authenticate` before doing *anything at all*, then even if they refresh the page on `/dashboard`, the `/authenticate` response will already be there so I don't have to worry about this obnoxious race condition. Can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

I'll do something like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean>  {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.getUser) this.getUser.unsubscribe();
      this.getUser = this.authService.getUser().subscribe(r => {
        resolve(true);
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

and this:

```
getUser(): Observable<UserDTO> {
    if (this.user) return new Observable(o => o.next(this.user));
    return this.http.get<UserDTO>(URL, { withCredentials: true })
      .pipe(
        map(u => new UserDTO(u)),
        tap(u => {
          this.user = u;
          this.isLogined = true;
        })
      );
  }
```

and remove logic from component. this must be in guard.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly this is doing? A lot of your code here isn't even what I use. Tried to get this working with what I have and it isn't working.